# How can I change the volume level of the dictation sound in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, sound-volume, voice-dictation

In iOS 12, the system make a sound when you start and stop dictating.  This sound is very loud and I cannot find a way to change the volume.  ["Problem 1", here](https://www.ikream.com/2019/05/iphone-8-sound-text-dictation-feature-cant-turned-off-sound-issues-27317) describes the issue, too.

In older versions of iOS, this was adjustable with the system volume level.  Now it is not.  Is this a bug, a feature, or is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the keyboard active in any app or swipe down on home screen.
2. Press the Mic icon.
3. You don't need to say something, just hold down volume down button. Press the Keyboard icon to get out of dictation.

It will be muted afterwards. Your music and ringer volume will remain unchanged. I discourage doing this as the phone is then recording your sound which is something the company wants to warn you about.

Comment: Thanks, I must have pressed the volumes buttons while dictating, sometime.  I don't need it off — i agree with you.  But the volume was at 100%... just awful.

Comment: @NewAlexandria 100% is default.

Comment: Fantastic. So this is a hidden "voice dictation volume level" that is independent of the volumes for rings, music, etc. Is this the only way to change it?

Comment: @JessRiedel a c c e s s i b i l i t y

Comment: Are you saying this sound level is adjustable through Settings > Accessibility? Where exactly? I have looked and cannot find it.